# Compile a tex file without equation

Tags: compiling

I have a document with many equations and mathematical terms in different lines in the text but for some reason, I would like to compile the document without these equations (but without removing mathematical expressions in the text).

I use following packages

```
\documentclass[english,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=blue {hyperref}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: see the comment package and declare your math environments as comments

Comment: Instead of the comment package (which I think generates a lot of IO), the environ package can do something similar, it will gather up the contents of the env in question and either use it, or give it to a macro (see `\Collect@Body`) then never use that macro.